# Vim autoindent on new line using 6 spaces instead of 4

Tags: vim, indentation

I have the following settings to make sure tab uses 4 spaces in my vimrc:

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
```

As well as `filetype plugin indent on`.

Yet when I press enter for a new line, the autoindentation puts 6 spaces. Shouldn't it put 4 because my tab is set to 4 spaces?

Comment: It might no longer be 4, the filetype plugin could have changed it. Try `:verbose set shiftwidth?`, it should show where the option was last set. Also, is `indentexpr` set? IIRC, it's not actually required that these should honour the tab width (but most do).

Comment: Why wouldn't it be 4 anymore? When I type the verbose command it shows `shiftwidth=4`. Also, indentexpr is not set

Comment: Due to the order of commands running: vim starts, `.vimrc` is sourced. You open a buffer with the relevant filetype, the filetype plugin runs. The plugin is free to do whatever to the settings in `.vimrc`. (After that, a filetype-specific `after` script is sourced, if present, which, in turn, is free to apply whatever correction is deemed necessary. That's where I normally keep my `shiftwidth` and similar).

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a vim newbie so don't really catch ur drift. Could you explain in simpler terms and how I could get it working as intended?

Comment: The above comment was just an explanation how a different value could end up in `shiftwidth`, `:help startup` has more detail on the topic. It doesn't seem to happen in your case, though. Is the indentation consistent for all filetypes, or does some specific one produce this behaviour?

Comment: I see.. i just tried on python and C and there doesn't seem to be a problem with those filetypes. Seems like a problem specific to java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193112/discussion-between-michail-and-doctopus).